# Remove specific character in pandas column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

**What I have**

Pandas frame with the following

```
ID Score
 0   50
 1   60
 2   70.5
 3   65.5
 4   56.5.6
 5   56.5.6.7
 6   10.
 7   56.0.
 8   56.5.0.
```

**What I am trying to do**

In column score, remove the dot if it occurs at the end

** How it would look like**

```
ID Score
 0   50
 1   60
 2   70.5
 3   65.5
 4   56.5.6
 5   56.5.6.7
 6   10
 7   56.0
 8   56.5.0
```

So basically, if the dot occurs at the end, it should be simply be removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) method, which removes trailing characters:

```
df['Score'] = df.Score.str.rstrip('.')

>>> df
   ID     Score
0   0        50
1   1        60
2   2      70.5
3   3      65.5
4   4    56.5.6
5   5  56.5.6.7
6   6        10
7   7      56.0
8   8    56.5.0
```